# How do I turn the URL from the .get() event handler into a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code setup:

```
$.get('/blog.html', function(data){
    // Do something
});
```

Can I take the '/blog.html' attribute and turn it into a variable? I'd like to do something like this, but keep in mind that this function will repeat a couple times but with other URLs:

```
var URL = $.get('/blog.html').text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because it's asynchronous. The function that calls `.get()` has completed by the time the response comes back. You have to learn to think asynchronously.

This does work:

```
$.get('/blog.html', function(data){
   var URL = data;
});
```

Comment: I like the simplicity in this one, except that when I tested it via alert(), it pulled and displayed all of the HTML file's coding.

Comment: i guess I'm not super sure what you are hoping to do with the result of the GET request or why your variable is named URL ( because you already have a URL, it's `/blog.html`)

Answer (score 0):

If you need several requests to complete before you do something only after all the requests complete you can do something like:

```
function getData(url){
   return $.get(url).then(function(data){return data});
}

var req1  = getData('/blog.html'),
    req2  = getData('/about.html'),
    req3  = getData('/contacts.html');

$.when(req1, req2, req3).then(function(blogData, aboutData, contactsData){
   // all requests are done
   // do something with each of the argments

}).fail(function(){
   console.log("One of the requests failed');
})
```